# Styling ActionMode ActionBar in Android 5.0 Lollipop (with AppCompat)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, material-design

I used this tutorial to facelift my Holo app for Lollipop:
http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

What I have:

1. Theme

   ```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Toolbar layout

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
   ```
3. Activity inherited from ActionBarActivity with a ListFragment fragment in the multi-choice mode

   `getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);`

**Result**: The toolbar is OK. It uses the sepcified theme colors, but the ActionBar used by the ListFragment in the ActionMode (activated by tap-and-hold a list item) has the standard Dark.ActionBar colors. Also the popup menu of the action bar uses the dark theme.

I tried all the SO tricks, but still cannot solve that. I will appreciate any help.

BTW. I found that the dark colors of the ActionBar are caused by the toolbar's `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`, but have no idea how solve this, because this attribute is needed for the correct toolbar appearance.

[image: Toolbar with correct colors] [image: Dark ActionBar]

Answer (score 75):

Just add these two lines to the theme:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
<item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
```

Comment: After a lot of time spent on this problem, this actually works. Thx!

Comment: Wasted a lot of time trying to get this to work, only to realize that, in order to get this to work in AppCompat's Toolbar, you will have to remove the _"android:"_ portion of the item's name. Hoping that this helps any other people reading this thread :)

Comment: thanks! what about status bar color? it gets white when `actionmode` is showing?

Answer (score 3):

This might also be helpful in addition to [@Andrey Shcherbakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343365/andrey-shcherbakov)'s answer if you want to have more control of each individual color.

```
<!-- action bar title text color, icon color (ie: back icon, icons when editing text)-->
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFF00</item>

<!-- action bar background color-->
<item name="android:colorBackground">#444400</item>

<!-- color of line under contextual action bar-->
<item name="colorControlActivated">#00CC00</item>
```