# How to change the theme of contextual action bar

Tags: android

I have use toolbar in my app with style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/holo_blue</
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Search.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Then I used a contextual action bar and able to change the background color.

```
<style name="Search.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/actionModeColor</item>
</style>
```

But I am unable to change the background color of popup menu.

Here is the image

[image]

And I wanted the background color of popup menu to be white. I also tried to change the theme by `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar` in Search.ActionMode but it does nothing.

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: this answer maybe solve anyone that has the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/26997022/3940133

Comment: @HendraWD  May I know does stackoverflow.com/a/26997022/3940133  for for you? As I have difficult time to make it work for my case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101757/change-the-theme-of-overflow-menu-during-actionmode-actionbar-actionbarpopupth

Comment: Yes it worked for me @CheokYanCheng

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to change the colors in Actionbar Use ActionBar Generator:

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

and copy paste all file in your res folder and change your theme in Android.manifest file.

Comment: It is using 9-patch and I want it through style.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem as yours. What I did is

I changed from

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

solve the problem. (Not exactly sure the reason behind)

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114013/72437)